# how to read properties file?

Tags: java, spring, properties, cxf

I am using CXF to create a java web service.

i have a file path, e.g "C:\ftproot", need to be configurable 
so i want to put this path into a properties file e.g application.properties

but how can i read the properties file in my java code?

can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the properties file in your `resources` or `WEB-INF/classes`

Then

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try {
    properties.load(new FileInputStream("classpath:application.properties"));
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

**See Also**

- [Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

Comment: I wonder, is there any Spring hook that allows `classpath:` URL resolving? Generally, this URL should not work in Java (see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596155/not-able-to-load-properties-file-in-java/7596193#7596193)), unless you register the URL handler e.g. via [`URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148350/how-to-register-url-handler-for-apache-commons-httpclient/148390#148390) or via `java.protocol.handler.pkgs` system property.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` for Spring (Refer to the API for options).

Example:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:build.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:other.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Assuming you have a property `file.path` in the property file and you are using component scanning you can then use:

```
@Value("file.path") private String filePath;
```

That will then be populated with the value of `file.path` in the property file (if the bean is created by Spring)

Or if you are creating your beans in XML:

```
<bean class="yourClassName">
    <property name="filePath" value="${file.path} />
</bean>
```