# Not able to load properties file in Java

Tags: java, properties

I am trying to load a properties file. The properites file is in the class path of the application.

```
 Properties p = new Properties();
 p.load(new FileInputStream("classpath:mail.properties"));
 System.out.println(p.get("hi"));
```

Now I say classpath, because another file called x.properties is referred in an xml file like this

```
<property name="x">
    <util:properties location="classpath:x.properties" />
</property>
```

I placed my mail.properties in the same folder as x.properties, but my Java program is not able to find it ? Any idea what I am missing ?

Answer (score 5):

Just because **some program** processing that XML file likes the syntax `classpath:x.properties` doesn't mean that it is a universally accepted syntax **in Java**!

If you provide `"classpath:x.properties"` to a `FileInputStream` it will *look for a file named* `classpath:x.properties`. (Check the documentation of that particular constructor.)

Try providing the full path to that file. If the file happens to be on your class path, you could use something like

```
p.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("mail.properties"));
```

Comment: getClass() of which class. For example if I am running the main method from TestProgram, should it be TestProgram.class.getClass().. ?

Comment: Then you can use `TestProgram.class.getResourceAsStream`.

Comment: hmm..I am getting the InputStream to be null.

Comment: Then that file is probably not available in the root of your class path.

Answer (score 1):

if mail.properties is indeed on your classpath, you will have better luck loading it via a class loader:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mail.properties");
p.load(is);
```

Comment: Hah. looks like there was some competition getting this in there first. Popped up just before I clicked post. ;)

Comment: @Thor84no - lol, your answer clicked up just before *I* clicked post.  Time/Space continuum issues? :D